# AWS Query - Accessing AWS instances behind proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, proxy

We are evaluating AWS for our cloud usage.
However our corp proxy is blocking the access of instances via SSH /RDP.

I checked with Ops team and they said they will allow ports for SSH and RDP.  But I have to give one source subnet and only one destination subnet /IP.

I am in ap-southeast-2 zone and there are nearly 27 subnets as per this including Global zones(For S3).
[AWS Subnets -Regionwise](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/05/08/amazon-web-services-aws-networking-public-ip-address-and-subnet-list/)

**Question**
1) Is there a way I can force AWS to create instances with in a particular IP range. ( I am thinking if I give one of the subnet from the 27, then I can give those subnet as destination to our Ops team.)

2) Can I do RDP Jumpbox ? meaning can I create one EC2 instance and then give IP of that machine to Ops for allowing access and then using that machine to RDP / SSH to other instances?

Please let me know the other options and your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with SSH tunnels?  Does your organization have IPv6 Internet connectivity?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : No. I have not got much idea on SSH tunnels.  No we dont have IPV6 internet connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

- There is no way to launch instances in a particular **public IP CIDR** and unless your CIDR is large that may include non-AWS IPs. One option is to allocate a bunch of elastic IPs (you are limited to only 10 EIPs by default), keeping the EIPs in the same /24 or /21 and releasing the rest. Even then there is no guarantee to get EIPs in the same small CIDR.
- SSH with Jumphost is easy and used by many. RDP with Jumphost may be possible but I am not sur how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am just exploring workspaces as well but I don't have much idea on that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way with the help of my colleague.
Luckily we had a guest network and we used that to achieve this.

**Steps**
1) I connected to both the LAN network and the guest network.
2) We referenced [Add Static Route- Microsoft documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_addstaticroute.mspx?mfr=true)

```
route add "destination" mask "subnetmask" "gateway" metric "costmetric" if interface
```

eg - `route add ec2InstanceIP mask 255.255.255.255 AlternateNetworkgateway METRIC 10`

Now I am able to do ssh, but RDP is not possible. Will explore and update if I find a way.